# Number of combinations for heteregeneous slots

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Definition:** Suppose you have a slot machine with *N*-number of slots. These slots have the property of being heterogeneous. That is, within each slot, the set of possible outcomes for slot *i*, $s_i$ are disjoint, i.e. $s_i \cup s_j = \emptyset$. Consequently, it is possible that $|s_i| \neq |s_j|$, where $|s_i|$ is the number of elements in the set.

**Example:** A slot machine has 2 heterogeneous slots, where slot 1's possible results are $\{a, b, c, d\}$ while slot 2's are $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

**Knowledge:** When the slot machine is played, the number of possible outcomes can be calculated as $\Pi_{i=1}^{N} |s_i|$. This is the number of combinations, since order doesn't matter. Also, no repetitions are allowed. For the example above, the number of combinations for the 2 slots are $4 \times 3 = 12$. The actual possible combinations are listed below for clarity.

```
{a, 1}
{a, 2}
{a, 3}
{b, 1}
{b, 2}
{b, 3}
{c, 1}
{c, 2}
{c, 3}
{d, 1}
{d, 2}
{d, 3}
```

**Special case:** Suppose any element in the slot sets could be replaced with one unique homogeneous value, e.g. `BLANK`. Following the example above, the combinations for this special case (ignoring repetitions) would be as follows.

```
{BLANK, 1}
{BLANK, 2}
{BLANK, 3}
{a, BLANK}
{b, BLANK}
{c, BLANK}
{d, BLANK}
{BLANK, BLANK}
```

**Question:** How do we calculate the number of combinations (excluding repetitions) for the special case above?

**Caveat:** For the case where $N = 2$, the solution seems to be $|s_1| + |s_2| + 1$. However, I'm interested in a general solution for any $N \geq 1$

**3-slot example:** The accepted answer was cross-checked using a 3-slot scenario, where $s_1 = \{a,b,c\}$, $s_2 = \{1,2\}$, and $s_3 = \{x\}$. The manually generated 18 combinations are as follows for anyone interested in cross-checking.

```
{NULL, 1, x}
{NULL, 2, x}
{a, NULL, x}
{b, NULL, x}
{c, NULL, x}
{a, 1, NULL}
{a, 2, NULL}
{b, 1, NULL}
{b, 2, NULL}
{c, 1, NULL}
{c, 2, NULL}
{NULL, NULL, x}
{NULL, 1, NULL}
{NULL, 2, NULL}
{a, NULL, NULL}
{b, NULL, NULL}
{c, NULL, NULL}
{NULL, NULL, NULL}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now have $s_i+1$ choices at position $i$ of the machine, but it appears you require at least one blank.  The number of combinations without the requirement is $\Pi_{i=1}^{N} |s_i+1|$ by the same logic as before.  The number if you require at least one blank is the number of new ones:  $\Pi_{i=1}^{N} |s_i+1|-\Pi_{i=1}^{N} |s_i|$

Comment: For verification of your answer, I manually generated the possible special case combinations for the 3-slot case, where $s_1=\{a,b,c\}$, $s_2=\{1,2\}$, and $s_3=\{x\}$. The result was 18 unique combinations, which validates to the proposed formula, i.e. $(4 \times 3 \times 2)−(3 \times 2 \times 1)=18$. Kudos! The question has been edited to show my manually generated results for the 3-slot example (for future reference/cross-checking)